# What commands would I use to solve this problem?

Tags: polynomials, homework, intervals

I'm new to Mathematica.

Starting from left to right give the intervals of a constant sign and the sign of the following polynomial on those intervals. Finally, I have to illustrate your results in two plots.

```
p[x_] = 
  -(16/81) + (2438 x)/405 - (218719 x^2)/8100 + (1111463 x^3)/21600 - 
  (79331 x^4)/1600 + (4779 x^5)/200 - (459 x^6)/100 -(16/81) + (2438 x)/405 - 
  (218719 x^2)/8100 + (1111463 x^3)/21600 - (79331 x^4)/1600 + (4779 x^5)/200 - 
  (459 x^6)/100
```

This what I got after I factored:
-(((-5 + 4 x)^2 (-8 + 9 x)^3 (-2 + 51 x))/64800)

The roots: 5/4, 8/9, 2/51.

I too frequently get stuck on graphing my solution. So that is what I need help with understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

p[x_] := -(16/81) + (2438 x)/405 - (218719 x^2)/8100 + (1111463 x^3)/
    21600 - (79331 x^4)/1600 + (4779 x^5)/200 - (459 x^6)/
    100 - (16/81) + (2438 x)/405 - (218719 x^2)/8100 + (1111463 x^3)/
    21600 - (79331 x^4)/1600 + (4779 x^5)/200 - (459 x^6)/100;
```

The function is negative in the intervals

```
neg = Reduce[p[x] < 0, x]

(* x < 2/51 || 8/9 < x < 5/4 || x > 5/4 *)
```

The function is zero at

```
roots = x /. Solve[p[x] == 0, x] // Union

(* {2/51, 8/9, 5/4} *)
```

The function is positive in the interval

```
pos = Reduce[p[x] > 0, x]

(* 2/51 < x < 8/9 *)
```

Graphically,

```
Plot[p[x], {x, 0, 3/2}, 
 ColorFunction :> (If[#2 > 0, Red, If[#2 < 0, Blue, Green]] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotPoints -> 300,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, p}),
 Epilog -> {
   Blue, Text[neg[[1]], {0.15, -0.2}],
   Red, Text[pos, {0.24, 0.22}],
   Blue, Text[neg[[2]], {77/72, 0.09}],
   Text[neg[[3]], {1.4, 0.09}],
   Green, AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Point[{#, 0} & /@ roots]}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[p[x], {x, 0.8, 1.32}, 
 ColorFunction :> (If[#2 > 0, Red, If[#2 < 0, Blue, Green]] &),
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 PlotPoints -> 300,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, p}),
 Epilog -> {
   Red, Text[pos, {0.87, 0.001}],
   Blue, Text[neg[[2]], {77/72, 0.001}],
   Text[neg[[3]], {1.3, 0.001}],
   Green, AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Point[{#, 0} & /@ roots]},
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a function.  You need to do so with `SetDelayed`,

```
p[x_] := -(16/81) + (2438 x)/405 - (218719 x^2)/8100 + (1111463 x^3)/
   21600 - (79331 x^4)/1600 + (4779 x^5)/200 - (459 x^6)/
   100 - (16/81) + (2438 x)/405 - (218719 x^2)/8100 + (1111463 x^3)/
   21600 - (79331 x^4)/1600 + (4779 x^5)/200 - (459 x^6)/100;

p[0.1]

0.362308
```

Then

```
Plot[p[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Or

```
Plot[p[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify the process by using `Mesh`,`MeshFunctions` and  `MeshShading`

```
p[x_] = -(16/81) + (2438 x)/405 - (218719 x^2)/8100 + (1111463 x^3)/
    21600 - (79331 x^4)/1600 + (4779 x^5)/200 - (459 x^6)/
    100 - (16/81) + (2438 x)/405 - (218719 x^2)/8100 + (1111463 x^3)/
    21600 - (79331 x^4)/1600 + (4779 x^5)/200 - (459 x^6)/100 // 
  Simplify

sols=Solve[p[x] == 0]

Plot[p[x], {x, 0.02, 1.4}, MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, 
 Mesh -> {x /. sols}, 
 MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Large], Green}, 
 Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

> `-(((5 - 4 x)^2 (-8 + 9 x)^3 (-2 + 51 x))/64800)`

> `{{x -> 2/51}, {x -> 8/9}, {x -> 8/9}, {x -> 8/9}, {x -> 5/4}, {x -> 5/ 4}}`
> [image]